# How to make an API to have results posted to Facebook

Tags: facebook, api

Does anybody know how to make an API to make my page results post to Facebook?

Or any social networking site?

I will post the code to my site here for anyone to take a look at it. Basically it is a site that allows users to take a survey and then based on those results, we recommend the most suitable dorm on campus. We need an API to post these results to Facebook. Here is my code for my site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<title> Find the right dorm for you </title>

<h1>Find out what dorm fits your lifestyle!</h1>

</head>
<body>
<p>Please fill out a few questions so we can 
help you figure out which dorm is best for you.</p>

<form method="get" action="final.php">

I enjoy (check all that apply):<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="8">Working Out<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="3">Bowling<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="3">Live Music<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="5">Shopping<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="7">Food<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="9">Bars <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="9">Frat Parties <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="8">Sports <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="acts" value="3">Library <br>


Is being close to the quad important to you?:
<select name= "Quad">
<option value="1">Not important</option>
<option value="3">Kind of important</option>
<option value="6">Very Important</option>
<option value="3">Only thing that matters</option>
</select>
<br>

How often do you plan on going to Red Lion?:
<select name= "Lion">
<option value="1">Never</option>
<option value="5">Sometimes</option>
<option value="10">Over 3 times a week</option>
</select>
<br>

Would you rather go to the ARC or CRCE?:
<select name= "Gym">
<option value="10">Arc</option>
<option value="1">CRCE</option>
</select>
<br>

How do you plan on eating most of your meals?:
<select name= "Meals">
<option value="5">Ordering delivery</option>
<option value="8">Walking To Green St.</option>
<option value="5">Making my own food</option>
</select>
<br>

Private or Public dorm?:
<select name= "Dorm">
<option value="10">Private</option>
<option value="5">Public</option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="get my results!">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and why will you do that when facebook already has the api

Comment: Satya-I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. I'm sorry I am very new to programming and have to do this for a class of mine. I just need to get users results to post to facebook, or any other social networking website. What do you mean that Facebook already has the api?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: or, would an I be able to make an API for my site that emails the users their results? It just needs to be a simple API and I am lost.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Jake Cooper, first you have to read some info about API's (http://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Application_programming_interface).
What you need here is to make use of the Facebook API.
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

Comment: @Phillip I put in the code to allow users to "like" my page and have that like show up on their facebook page. Is that considered API?

Answer (score 1):

For social networks, after deciding what services your page/application on your server is providing then you can decide how to start making an API.

Say your website has data on a number of residents in a dorm and you want others to communicate with this data without releasing passwords for your server/database. You could use an application programming interface.

In your case it seems you want a more basic form, i.e. exposing methods from a class for others to use. Consider looking into *software design patterns*

Once you have figured out that then you need understand other APIs such as Facebook. This you can do by reading more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

In summary an API is something the *owner* of the code creates to make it easier for *others* to use the code/services. If you just want code to post to Facebook, you don't need your own API you need to use the API provided by Facebook.

```
Provide an API to your services that will then be used to post to Facebook

--------    --------     --------    --------    --------
| Your |    | Your |     | Your |    | Joe  |    | Face |
| Dorm |----| Code |-----| API  |----| Code |----| book |
| Data |    |      |     |      |    |      |    |  API |
--------    --------     --------    --------    --------

Just need to post to Facebook

--------    --------     --------
| Your |    | Your |     | Face |
| Dorm |----| Code |-----| book |
| Data |    |      |     |  API |
--------    --------     --------
```